# Can't Full Screen Slitaz in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I got and installed VirtualBox Guest Additions by running `autorun.sh` and then `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` as root, but Slita still doesn't go full screen in Virtual Box running on Windows 7.

The max resolution is 800x600. I enabled 3d Acceleration in Settings too.

When installing Guest Additions I get

> Execution return code: 2 ex000020b: Unknown Error

How to go full screen?

Comment: You need to install the additions on the GUEST and then reboot the guest

Comment: @Bodhi.zazen

I did. It said everything was successful inside guest Slitaz. I rebooted it twice but nothing changes. I did just notice that I got a slightly higher resolution numbers available in Display Settings of the guest os but they are not native to my screen and are weird. Like this 943x623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Install Guest Additions on the Virtual machine. A guide and more information can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36500_01/E36502/html/qs-guest-additions.html).

Comment: I don't have "Install Guest Additions..." option. Only "Insert Guest Additions CD image..." but nothing happens.

If I try to mount the .iso with VirtualCloneDrive and install Additions I get an error with exit code of 2.

Comment: As soon as it start to install drivers I get the error that is. Error code ex000020b: Unknown Error

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using?

Comment: Actually  I just ran autorun.sh again and rebooted Guest OS. Now Full Screen works fine. Weird.